# telegram bot can't send messages to super group

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

this is my code

```
private async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
    {

        var message = e.Message; if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Text) return; await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Hello?");
```

in this case, it works well with super groups

but 
    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync([supergroup chat id], "Hello?");

put Super Group ID in here[supergroup chat id], it won't work.
I've set up all the group permissions.
After upgrading the super group, I had to drop the bot and invite again

Comment: have you turned off the bot's group privacy via Botfather?

Comment: I tried and tested various settings through Botfather, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 23):

Just in case if you are haven't figured it out already... When a group is upgraded to supergroup, new ID is generated:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 400,
    "description": "Bad Request: group chat was upgraded to a supergroup chat",
    "parameters": {
        "migrate_to_chat_id": -1001432162429
    }
}
```

Use this migrate_to_chat_id to send messages

Comment: I also had to remove and add my bot back to the members of my supergroup, otherwise bot was failing to send messages to the upgraded supergroup using the updated chat_id. But I am not sure that it was a requiered step.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the above 'migrate_to_chat_id' field mentioned by **piyushkantm** you can
use:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    console.log(chatId);
});
```

When your request fails send a test message to the group via mobile phone the above will return your updated super group chat.id.